# Ruby on rails : filter data by attributes, without call instance variable many times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap tabs, with 3 tabs : verified comments, unverified comments and all comments. Each tab-content displaying different comments depending to the RoR attribute :verified (true, or false). But I have a optimization problem, because I call `@ratings` (comments) 3 times, and filter the comments like that : `@ratings.where(:verified => true)`, and in production the application is really slow.

Someone know how could I filter verified, unverified and all with an other method ?

here is the code :

**show.html.erb**

```
<% if @school.ratings.count > 0 %>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
          <li role="presentation" class="<%= 'active' if @school.is_subscribed? %>">
                <a href="#verifie" aria-controls="verifie" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <h3>
                        Avis vérifiés (<%= @ratings.where(:verified => true).count %>)
                    </h3>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#non_verifie" aria-controls="non_verifie" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <h3>
                        Avis non-vérifiés (<%= @ratings.where(:verified => false).count %>)
                    </h3>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li role="presentation" class="<%= 'active' unless @school.is_subscribed? %>">
                    <a href="#all_avis" aria-controls="all_avis" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                        <h3>
                            Tous les avis (<%= @ratings.count %>)
                        </h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <%= 'active' if @school.is_subscribed? %>" id="verifie">
                    <%= render partial: "schools/rating", collection: @ratings.where(:verified => true) %>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="non_verifie">
                    <%= render partial: "schools/rating", collection: @ratings.where(:verified => false) %>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <%= 'active' unless @school.is_subscribed? %>" id="all_avis">
                    <%= render partial: "schools/rating", collection: @ratings %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#post-rating" id="post-rating-bottom-btn" class="btn btn-warning post-rating-btn"><%= fa_icon 'star' %>
                Laisser un avis</a>
        <% else %>
            <p>Pas encore d'avis sur cette auto-école. Soyez le premier
                <a id="post-rating-be-first" href="#post-rating" class="btn btn-warning post-rating-btn"><%= fa_icon 'star' %>
                    Donnez votre avis</a>
            </p>
        <% end %>
```

**schools_controller.erb**

```
@school = School.where(city_namespace: params[:city], title_namespace: params[:title]).first || raise(ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found'))
    @rating = Rating.new(params[:rating])
    @rating.school_id = @school.id
    @ratings = @school.ratings.desc(:created_at)
```

Don't hesitate if you need more code / infos !

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am personally not sure whether you're spending your server resources on multiple calls of the instance variables. I believe that your app is slow because you select the large amount of ActiveRecord objects (which are slow themselves). So my tips are:

In your controller you can simply initialize 3 instance variables:

```
@ratings = @school.ratings.desc(:created_at)
@verified_ratings = @ratings.where(:verified => true)
@unverified_ratings = @ratings.where(:verified => false)
```

Then just call them in your view. It's not about optimization but still.

**Tip 0.** If you need to select a few Rating records use pluck. With pluck you will not instantiate te ActiveRecord object but the arrays of arrays. Pass to pluck the symbols of columns you need to get. For example:
Rating.where(:verified => false).pluck(:column_1, :column_2)

**Tip 1.** To save your server resources you can use pagination to select data from DB by portions. Use [Kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) or [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gems.

**Tip 2.** If you're on Postgresql use [postgresql_cursor](https://github.com/afair/postgresql_cursor) gem to perform something like:

```
Rating.desc(:created_at).each_instance(block_size: SIZE_YOU_NEED).lazy.map { do_something }
```

It will load your data in batches. The size of batches can be changed (pass the value to `block_size`). You'll be able to sort the data in those batches (without `postgresql_cursor` gem you'll not be able to do that). One could say it's an alternative approach to pagination.

Comment: Calling it in the controller doesn't save any time in db calls though, but it's cleaner code.

Comment: @VAD thank you for the help, but my boss refuse a pagination, he want all the comments on the same page for each tabs ..

Comment: @AntoninMrchd, added more tips